# I need help this code on Python mysql connector, I keep on getting errors

Tags: python, mysql

```py
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='**********', host='localhost', database='Grocery_Store')
cnx.close()

cursor = cnx.cursor()

query = "SELECT * FROM Grocery_Store.Products;"
cursor.excecute(query)

for (Products_id, Products_name, UOM_id, Price_per_unit) in cursor:
    print(Products_id, Products_name, UOM_id, Price_per_unit)

cnx.close()
```

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.10 /Users/gabriel-dee/Grocery Application/Backend/Products_dao.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gabriel-dee/Grocery Application/Backend/Products_dao.py", line 6, in <module>
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 622, in cursor
    raise OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.")
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='MySQLgabmal77#', host='localhost', database='Grocery_Store') cnx.close() -> You are closing the connection directly after creating it.

Comment: Don't post your credentials in public websites.

Comment: can you please be specific @Guy

Comment: @Gabriel I don't know how to be more specific than that... you posted your username and password where everybody can see.

Comment: I noticed that thank you Guy

Answer (score 1):

You `close` your connection immediately after creating it:

```py
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='password', host='localhost', database='database')
cnx.close() # Remove this one
```

The second call to `cnx.close()` seems to be in the right place. Remove the first one and you should be OK.